# Scriptmanager on one page, but the Panel on another

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

Im having a .Master page with

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MasterIndhold_Member" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And inside the ContentPlaceHolder I got an Panel with a FileUpload. The thing is that the FileUpload doesn't find the file. Here I want to add RegisterAsyncPostBackControl to the Scriptmanager, but how do I do this when the panel is on another page?

The nested page code looks like this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterIndhold_Member" runat="server">
    <asp:panel runat="server" ID="Panel_MyProfile_Member" Visible="false">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="File1" runat="server" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkUploadImageMember" runat="server" onclick="LinkUploadImageMember_Click">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
```

And the CodeBehind for the FileUpload Looks like this

```
protected void LinkUploadImageMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File1.HasFile == true)
        {
            if ((File1.PostedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".jpg")) || (File1.PostedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".jpeg")) || (File1.PostedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".png")))
            {
                    byte[] input = File1.FileBytes;
                    Bruger.UploadImage(input, int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Please keep code examples to C# and ASP.NET as I'm new to this stuff ^^

Thanks

Comment: Well I found this solution

ScriptManager scriptmanager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
                            scriptmanager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl();

But the thing is, I don't know exactly what to fill in RegisterAsyncPostBackControl

Comment: The visible flag of the Panel will be set to true, I guess? What do you mean with "the FileUpload doesn't find the file"? How big is the file you are uploading?

Comment: Yea the panel is set to visible = true, by the time the code get's to the upload part.

Whenever I upload a file (8,70 KB) the File1.HasFile = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx) class if you need a ScriptManager on your content page, but I'm not sure whether you need this at all. Do you really need an UpdatePanel on every content page? (because you declared it on the master page). I think it might be better to declare the UpdatePanel within the content page.

Try to define a trigger for your linkbutton, otherwise HasFiles is always false

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkUploadImageMember" />
  </Triggers>

  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="File1" runat="server" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkUploadImageMember" runat="server" Text=" upload " />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you cannot remove the UpdatePanel from the Masterpage, you could expose a property on the masterpage that gives access the updatepanel, like this:

```
public UpdatePanel MyUpdatePanel 
{
    get { return UpdatePanel1; }
}
```

From the contentpage you can access the update panel and update the triggers programmatically:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ((Site)Master).MyUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(new PostBackTrigger() {
              ControlID = LinkUploadImageMember.UniqueID });
}
```

Comment: The reason for the UpdatePanels on each page is that the page looks different for some Users ^^

Comment: The <Trigger> tag isn't valid within a <Panel> tag, would you suggest that I put the trigger in the <UpdatePanel> on the .master page, and set the <Trigger> ControlID = the upload button on the nested page?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that would work, at least not in my test project. I personally find it better to put the UpdatePanel on the content page. The update area should be as small as possible anyway.

Comment: I see.

Any way you would be able to fix it in it's current state, because right now it's not a possible to reduce the size of the <UpdatePanel>.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but gets the error that "Site is 'property' but is used as a 'type'". What does that mean? are there a step i missed?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code. Does your property have the name UpdatePanel? Or maybe your Masterpage does not have the type Site like mine.

Comment: Cam I add the type Site to my MasterPage

Comment: Site is the type of my MasterPage class, I don't know how yours is called. Master is the property within the page to access the MasterPage and I cast to the corresponding type (in my case Site).

Comment: How can I see what type my masterpage is?

Comment: At the top of your master page you find the @Master tag. There is an attribute called Inherits which defines the class. Or you find it in the code behind file. I would suggest that you read a good asp.net book, before you go on, otherwise you will have many open questions ;-)